# How to wait or delay a code in my CS code

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to create a waiting sequence or the lines appear after a specified time.

I tried `Task.Sleep(number);`  and `await Task.Delay(2000);` but no.. nothing works.

VSC says The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Have you tried `using System.Threading.Tasks;`?

Comment: Next time: Put the cursor on `Task` and press F1 for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add async Task to your method, without testing it something like should work:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Simple;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```